# Rshiny: Reduce the process time of filtering df from the selected dropdown for all components

Tags: r, shiny

My dashboard have multiple components/ graph and all the components  will go through the same process of filtering and choosing the correct df based on my dropdown selection. is there any way to able reduce the process by only run this filtering process once for all components.

Here are the filtering example:

```
if(input$comp_region == "USA"){
  txn_df <- usa_df
}else if(input$comp_region == "Australia"){
  txn_df <- aus_df
}else{
  txn_df <- jpn_df
}

txn_df <- txn_df %>% 
  filter(user_type %in% input$user) %>% 
  filter(date == input$time) %>%
```

Comment: How many different combinations of options are there? How does that relate to filtering for different components, are those processes identical and using the same variables? Would be nice to have a concrete example of your input and expected output

Comment: @DonaldSeinen there are about 3 combo (region, user type, month), and Yes the process for all components starts with the identical filtering and using the same variables

Comment: nevermind already found it, i'm using reactive dataframe now

Comment: Alright - might want to answer your own question. Some tips on speed > `dplyr::filter` is quite slow, might want to use another backend if you do a lot of subsetting. Further, `user_type %in% input$user & date == input$time` saves 1 call to `filter`, and translation of the `if else` into a `switch` statement might save lot of checks if you have more than 3 regions.